# Cant get complete array in php from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

In phpmyadmin I Get the result expected, it means, daily number of vacations in a range of days, however I can't make it work on PHP and I get only the firs row of the whole array.

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "andes", "andes123","andes");
$query= "select calendar_table.dt, count(BP) as 'Number'
from calendar_table
left join tbl021_vacaciones on calendar_table.dt between
tbl021_vacaciones.fecha_inicio and tbl021_vacaciones.fecha_fin
where (calendar_table.dt between '2016-01-29' and '2016-03-31')
group by calendar_table.dt";
$request=mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($request);
$Resultado= print_r ($row['dt'], $row['Number']);
```

I know that I am doing it wrong, but I cannot make it work to save the results into a single PHP

Comment: Please make your problem clear and understandable.

Comment: also `print_r()` prints and array so you would code it as `print_r($row)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch all results you need to loop :

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($request)) {
 //echo $row['dt'];
}
```

Comment: But I am using mysqli

Comment: yeah i didnt saw the "i" my bad :D

Comment: `while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $request ) )
{
    print_r ( $row );
}`

That was the answer!

Answer (score 0):

To obtain all the rows of a mysqli query:

```
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all( $request, MYSQLI_ASSOC );
```

or:

```
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $request ) )
{
    print_r( $row['dt'] );
}
```

`MYSQLI_ASSOC` means to fetch only as associative arrays. Otherwise, you will obtain both numeric and associative index, like in your example (BTW, this is not an error in your original code).

Comment: _this is not a problem at all_ if you dont mind using DOUBLE the necessary memory

Comment: ^ @RiggsFolly Yes, you are right. I means that is not the problem of the question. I'll update answer, thank you.